# JRE 1.7 compatibility with win7(x64)

Tags: java

Is jre 1.7 (32 bit) compatible with windows 7 64 bit OS ?

I am using jre 1.7 update 9. When I login into the application, it is not opening. This is a jre issue but I wanted to know if 64 bit OS supports 32 bit jre. Application works fine with a 64 bit jre. But I want to make it 32 bit compliant.

Comment: Yes. It should be backwards compatible afaik.

Comment: No, If you want to build 32bit application then you must have 32bit jre to run your application smoothly.

Comment: YES, 32 bit jre 1.7 is compatible with 64 bit OS windows 7

Comment: Check your system has JRE 1.7 of 32bit or not ?

Comment: yes i tried to run my application with 32 bit jre on 64 bit OS but my application does not open. The Java Console also does not open.If 32 bit jre is compatible with 64 bit OS can anyone let me know where should I check the settings to run the application??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 32bit JRE can run on Windows 64bit.

You are saying that you're trying to "log into" your application. Is that an Applet?
If so, then you have to ensure that your browser runs in 32bit mode:

1. If you install the 32bit JRE, then the Java Plugin (allowing you to run Applets) will only work under 32bit browsers.
2. If you install the 64bit JRE, then the Java plugin will only work under 64bit browsers.
3. To support both 32bit and 64bit browsers, you have to install both JRE's.